# google analytics shows more unique visits than apache log

Tags: apache, google-analytics

When i compare google analytics "active users"(as i understand this means the unique visits per period of time) with the apache log, i always get the results that google analytics shows more unique visits than the apache log. Why is this?

Comment: Check for referral spam (https://www.google.de/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=google%20analytics%20referral%20spam), this might produce more traffic in the reports than you have on your website.

Comment: but the apache log should also record them, no?

Comment: No. Spammers can send data to your GA Account without ever visiting your website,

Comment: thank you, i already checked it and really found that several refferals are indeed spam bots, and thanks to the post you sent i checked the "filter known bots" in google analytics settings, but the numbers are still far from what they should be.

Comment: do these bots enter as direct visits or only as reffered?

Comment: As reffered is sure... but i am not sure about direct because i cannot check it. But i guess that they enter as direct also, otherwise i have no explanation to the numbers i get from GA compared to apache log.